# AJAX POST can reach "success" but passed variables don't exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem with AJAX. I'm trying to POST variable from JQuery from 1 file to another file. When I use **a tag** "Pokračovať" to redirect myself to next page where I want to use POST variable, it says it doesn't exist. Here's my code:

HTML echoed via PHP:

```
echo "
      <div id=posMid>
      <div id=postage>          
      <div data-value='Slovenská pošta-1,99€' class=pick>Slovenská pošta - 1,99€ (doručenie do 3 pracovných dní)</div>
      <div data-value='Kuriér-3,99€' class=pick>Kuriér - 3,99€ (doručenie nasledujúci pracovný deň)</div>
      <div data-value='Osobne-0,00€' class=pick>Odber osobne na pobočke - bez poplatkov</div>
      </div><!--
      --><div id=pay>
      <div data-value='Na účet-0,00€' class=pick>Platba na účet - bez poplatkov (overenie do 3 dní)</div>
      <div data-value='Platba kartou-0,00€' class=pick>Platba kartou - bez poplatkov (overenie ihneď)</div>
      <div data-value='Dobierka-2,99€' class=pick>Dobierka - 2,99€ (platba pri prevzatí)</div>
      </div>
      </div>"; 


echo "<div id=navCart>
      <a href='cart.php' id=Back>Späť do košíka</a>
      <a href='cartStep3.php' id=Next>Pokračovať</a></form>
      </div>";
```

JQuery:

```
$('#posMid #postage .pick').click(function(){
$(this).parent().find('.pick').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
var postage = $(this).attr('data-value');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cartStep3.php",
    data:{ post: postage }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(postage); 
    }
  });
});
```

Please help, I really don't know where's the problem.

---

Postage sent:

[image: postage sent]

Response received:

[image: response]

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: In browser it shows that request was done and in raw data tab it shows my variable. JQuery is included, only error is that I mentioned in question: **Undefined index: post** . I have website hosted so yeah.

Comment: @chiro it's undefined because you are not receiving the parameter from function success correctly I displayed the reason and answer below in Answers section

Comment: If you have ***undefined index: post*** then you are not sending the value for postage to the PHP script. Change `$(this).attr('data-value');` to `$(this).data('value');` and make sure postage contains what you expect.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well, if I use value instead of data-value postage is empty. With data-value it works, it also shows in console log if I use 'console.log(postage); ' .

Comment: OK. Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Like what part now ? Because I'm not doing anything in cartStep3.php now except echoing POST variable.

Comment: @chiro how are you echoing it?

Comment: So, you're doing `echo $_POST['post'];` ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard of course you understand it has to be passed in json ?

Comment: I tried `echo $_POST['post'];` and also `$test=$_POST['post']; echo $test;` . But both don't work.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be passed in JSON. The OP has not specified a `dataType` for return, so plain text will be returned if he echos correctly.

Comment: Put `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your PHP file to see what is in the POST array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Fairpoint Thanks for the information

Comment: @JayBlanchard but he would still have to call data.post then correct?

Comment: For passing I used code from Jacobs answer but it says same thing about being not defined.

Comment: He has to get the PHP side working before the return will @JacobWebb He could just do `console.log(data)` before breaking it down - if it needs to be broken down.

Comment: When I print Post it only show an empty array: **Array()**

Comment: @chiro i fixed up an ajax call and php return method try it out and tell me if it works replaced old answer with new one.

Comment: Let's get the basics working before throwing in JSON @JacobWebb JSON is not necessary for a single response item.

Comment: @JacobWebb Tried that new code but POST array is still empty.

Comment: Remove everything from your click handler but setting `postage` and the AJAX call. Then try it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand that. Could the reason its not working is because its in slovak

Comment: If the OP is UTF-8 all the way through then it shouldn't be a problem @JacobWebb

Comment: @JayBlanchard perhaps the document is not ready to be fired yet and does not see it? might I suggest $(document).ready( )

Comment: I use UTF-8. I removed those 2 lines above declaration of postage but still, Post is empty.

Comment: @chiro in php try using $_GET['post']

Comment: The click works though @JacobWebb, because the PHP script fires.

Comment: `type: "POST",` so nothing will be in `$_GET` @JacobWebb

Comment: @chiro you're sure there are no other errors in the browser's console?

Comment: The OP may have left us swinging in the wind @JacobWebb

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nope, just some warnings about css.

Comment: @JayBlanchard haha

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  @JacobWebb

Comment: @chiro when you look at the network tab in the browser's developer tools do you see the post request with the proper value? Network->XHR->Headers tab

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, it's there with the correct value.

Comment: Let's try changing this - just in the event we have a keyword problem: `data:{ postage: postage },` I am assuming the PHP script is still just `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Is the URL for this public?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't understand ? Should I change it to `postage : postage `?

Comment: Yes, you should. `postage: postage` will show up in the `$_POST['postage']` with the right value if everything works OK

Comment: URL for php file with print ? Yeah it's accessable via link.

Comment: Post that URL please.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Changing it has same result.

Comment: [link](http://pcshop.webz.cz/php/cartStep3.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard hes not alerting it correctly he needs to change his console.log(data) to console.log(data.postage) after he echos $postage from his php

Comment: It still isn't set @JacobWebb, so no amount of change to the AJAX success will fix that.

Comment: @chiro where is the form that you click on - do you have that link?

Comment: @JayBlanchard [link](http://pcshop.webz.cz/php/cartStep2.php) here, U pick something in left white div and then click on "pokračovať"

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh yeah I have some conditions there sorry, Go here [link](http://pcshop.webz.cz/php/tovar.php?tovar=ZD)  than click on "Kupiť" under any picture and than click "pokračovať" and you should see 2 divs.

Comment: I see it now. When I click on one of the items it performs the AJAX request and returns a truckload of HTML. The problem isn't the code - it's the logic. Once an item is picked, the AJAX runs right away but the variable is no longer available when you click  "pokračovať". What you need to do is rethink your logic for what you want done when you click  "pokračovať". I am adding two images to your original post to show you what I see.

Comment: @JacobWebb the AJAX wasn't failing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh, so I guess I have to somehow rework "pokračovať" and it's task to make variable available on next page. Ok thanks for pointing that out. I will work on it tommorow, it's 10PM in here and I have school tommorow so. Thanks for sticking with me for such a long time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard hmm we were looking in the wrong place the whole time Facepalm

Comment: It happens all the time @JacobWebb

Comment: @JayBlanchard welp nice meeting you see you around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see it now. When I click on one of the items it performs the AJAX request and returns a truckload of HTML. The problem isn't the code - it's the logic. Once an item is picked, the AJAX runs right away but the variable is no longer available when you click "pokračovať". What you need to do is rethink your logic for what you want done when you click "pokračovať". I am adding two images to your original post to show you what I see. – Jay Blanchard 11 mins ago